Update wsl2 kernel version from github offline
The newest version of docker desktop requires wsl2 kernel version 5.15.146.1-2 at least.
However, the latest version of wsl_update_x64.msi from official site is 5.10.102.2. To get docker desktop running, user has to update wsl2 kernel version by 'wsl --update --web-download'. However, for security reasons, some of the windows hosts do not have Internet access. Is there a way to update wsl2 kernel to latest version offline?
I tried compile from wsl2 kernel 5.15.146.1-2 release source code in a wsl2 ubuntu distro and got a binary file named vmlinux, but I don't know how to use it to update my windows host's wsl2 kernel. I'm expecting either these two solutions:
1 we build a update source by forking from github source periodly in our local network.
2 We build update package for windows from source code of latest release on github
I'm not familiar with either way and need help. Thank you very much

+1 on this. I am having the exact same issue.
I ended out simply downgrading to docker v4.24.2 instead. (https://docs.docker.com/desktop/release-notes/#4242)
That solved the issue for me, as the dependency for wsl2 kernel 5.15.146.1-2 was introduced in docker v4.25.0.
Definitely not the best solution, but it might help some.
